# If I manually insert a record in rdb, will it show up in downstream?

Tags: kdb

If there is a instance subscribe to rdb, and I manually insert a record to rdb's table, will this publish to that instance?

Please kindly provide an example.

Answer (score 2):

Under standard kdb+ tick architecture, the RDB does not expose any pub/sub functionality. The RDB will instead subscribe to the TP (Tickerplant). Other components can also subscribe to the TP.

I have heard of implementations where pub/sub features are added to an RDB. If this is this case, inserting a record into a table will most likely not result in it being published downstream (but it depends on how RDB pub/sub has been implemented in your case)

If however, you meant a TP and not an RDB in the original question, then inserting a record into a table in the TP will result in it being published to downstream subscribers either on (1) the next `.u.upd` call on the TP or (2) timer invocation if TP is in batch mode.

But this is not the correct way to get a record published downstream. The correct way is to invoke the `.u.upd` (TP) / `upd` (RDB) function on the process.

For example:

```
On TP:
    .u.upd[<tableName>;<tableData>]
On RDB:
    upd[<tableName>;<tableData>]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. How come if there is pub/sub feature in rdb, downstream instance will not be updated? but it will be updated if it is tp/rdb?

Comment: @Terry it is the job of the tickerplant to relay messages to subscribers, not the RDB. If you want to do this, you need to set up chained tickerplants

Comment: i understand it is tp's job. however, if there is pub/sub feature in rdb, are they still not the same?